# Magento 2 applying tax class on ALL product SQL query

Tags: magento2

you can use SQL query for the update all product tax class and it will save your time, attribute id you can find from the attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_int` SET `value` =2 WHERE `attribute_id` =133
```